# A* Implementation broken?

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, path-finding, search

I tried implementing [Wikipedia's version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) of the A* pathfinding algorithm, but when I run it in Unity the object which the script is applied to does nothing and Unity ends up taking 15% of my CPU. I feel like this is a stack overflow error, but I can't tell where it breaks down. Here's the entirety of the script:

```
public class Walker : MonoBehaviour {

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public MapView core { get; set; }
    public Node goal { get; set; }

    public float DistanceBetween(Node a, Node b) {
        return Mathf.Abs(a.x - b.x) + Mathf.Abs(a.y - b.y);
    }

    public List<Vector3> FindPath(Node goal) {
        Node start = new Node(x, y);

        List<Node> open = new List<Node>();
        open.Add(start);
        List<Node> closed = new List<Node>();

        Dictionary<Node, Node> cameFrom = new Dictionary<Node, Node>();

        Dictionary<Node, float> gScore = new Dictionary<Node, float>();
        gScore[start] = 0;

        Dictionary<Node, float> fScore = new Dictionary<Node, float>();
        fScore[start] = DistanceBetween(start, goal);

        while (open.Count != 0) {

            Node current = open[0];


            foreach (Node n in fScore.Keys)
                if (fScore[n] < fScore[current])
                    current = n;

            if (current == goal)
                return ReconstructPath(cameFrom, current);

            open.Remove(current);
            closed.Add(current);

            foreach (Node neighbor in Neighbors(current)) {

                if (closed.Contains(neighbor))
                    continue;
                float tempGScore = gScore[current] + DistanceBetween(current, neighbor);

                if (!open.Contains(neighbor))

                    open.Add(neighbor);

                else if (tempGScore >= gScore[neighbor])
                    continue;

                cameFrom[neighbor] = current;
                gScore[neighbor] = tempGScore;
                fScore[neighbor] = gScore[neighbor] + DistanceBetween(neighbor, goal);
            }
        }

        return new List<Vector3>();
    }

    public List<Vector3> ReconstructPath(Dictionary<Node, Node> cameFrom, Node current) {
        List<Vector3> path = new List<Vector3>();
        path.Add(current.GetVector());
        while (cameFrom.ContainsKey(current)) {
            current = cameFrom[current];
            path.Add(current.GetVector());
        }
        return path;
    }

    public List<Node> Neighbors(Node current) {
        int currx = current.x;
        int curry = current.y;

        List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>();
        neighbors.Add(new Node(currx, curry - 1));
        neighbors.Add(new Node(currx, curry + 1));
        neighbors.Add(new Node(currx - 1, curry));
        neighbors.Add(new Node(currx + 1, curry));
        return neighbors;
    }

    public virtual void SetStartCoords() {
        x = (int)transform.position.x;
        y = (int)transform.position.z;
    }
}

public class Node {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Node(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Vector3 GetVector() {
        return new Vector3(x, 0, y);
    }
}
```

Could I be misusing the DistanceBetween() function incorrectly, since I'm using it to calculate both the gScore and fScore of each node?

Edit: I tried a new implementation, but Unity is still not even responding. @ratchet-freak @bálint

```
public class Walker {
    public List<Vector3> FindPath(Node goal) {
        Node start = new Node(x, y);

        SimplePriorityQueue<Node> open = new SimplePriorityQueue<Node>();
        open.Enqueue(start,0);

        List<Node> closed = new List<Node>();

        while (open.Count != 0) {

            Node current = open.Dequeue();

            foreach (Node neighbor in Neighbors(current)) {

                if (neighbor == goal)
                    return ReconstructPath(neighbor);

                neighbor.gScore = DistanceBetween(current, neighbor);
                neighbor.hScore = DistanceBetween(neighbor, goal);
                neighbor.fScore = neighbor.gScore + neighbor.hScore;

                bool skip = false;

                foreach (Node n in open)
                    if (n == neighbor && n.fScore < neighbor.fScore)
                        skip = true;
                foreach (Node n in closed)
                    if (n == neighbor && n.fScore < neighbor.fScore)
                        skip = true;

                if (!skip)
                    open.Enqueue(neighbor, neighbor.fScore);
            }

            closed.Add(current);
        }

        return new List<Vector3>();
    }

    public List<Vector3> ReconstructPath(Node current) {
        List<Vector3> path = new List<Vector3>();
        path.Add(current.GetVector());
        while (current.cameFrom != null) {
            current = current.cameFrom;
            path.Add(current.GetVector());
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fScore should be the sum of the hScore and the gScore, and gScore should be a node-based distance

Comment: Isn't hScore the distance from the current tile to the next, and gScore the distance from start to the current tile?

Comment: hScore (heuristic) is the distance from the current tile to the last, it's an approximation. gScore Is the distance from the start point to the next point on the tiles. It's basically the gScore of the last tile + the distance between the tiles.

Comment: So shouldn't gScore[current] + DistanceBetween(current, neighbor) work for the gScore of the neighbor tile, since it adds the accumulative gScores of everything from the start point up to the neighboring tile?

Comment: that should work

Comment: Huh it's what I already had though

Comment: Tried another implementation using a priorityqueue but it's still not responding (put it in the main post)

Answer (score 1):

Doing a linear scan over the entire open set and then doing a `Remove` (which is also O(n)) is not going to help performance. A good implementation uses a heap of some sort for the open set where you can pop the next node in O(log n) and update the neighbours in the set also in O(log n).

`closed.Contains(neighbor)` where closed is a List means that this is a O(n) operation instead use a Set with a O(1) contains operation.

Related to this many implementations will create a

```
struct{
    Node cameFrom; 
    float gScore;
    float fScore;
    bool closed;
}
```

So that you don't need 3 different dictionaries.

Comment: What's the difference between a struct and a class, or would it be a good idea to put those variables into the node class I have right now instead of making a struct?

Comment: struct here is meant as a value type (allocated in place) while class is a reference type (allocated on the heap). And yes you can put that information straight into the node class.

Comment: I tried a new implementation but Unity is still crashing (put it in the main post)